# Loop and update without cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, query-optimization

I have a table where item balances are stored.

```
CREATE TABLE itembalance (
   ItemID VARCHAR(15),
   RemainingQty INT,
   Cost Money,
   Id INT
)
```

I need to make sure that whenever an item is being sent out, the proper balances are deducted from the itembalance table. I do it this way:

```
DECLARE crsr CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR 
        SELECT 
           itembalance.Cost, 
           itembalance.RemainingQty
           itembalance.Id
        FROM dbo.itembalance
        WHERE itembalance.ItemID = @v_item_to_be_updated AND RemainingQty > 0

OPEN crsr
FETCH crsr
INTO 
  @cost, 
  @qty, 
  @id

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN
IF @qty >= @qty_to_be_deducted
BEGIN
    UPDATE itembalance SET RemainingQty = RemainingQty - @qty_to_be_deducted WHERE Id = @id

    /*do something with cost*/ BREAK
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE itembalance SET RemainingQty = 0 WHERE Id = @id
    /*do something with cost*/ SET @qty_to_be_deducted = @qty_to_be_deducted - @qty
END
FETCH crsr
INTO 
  @cost, 
  @qty, 
  @id


END
CLOSE crsr
DEALLOCATE crsr
```

The table may contain same item code but with different cost. This code is okay for few items being updated at a time but whenever a lot of items/quantities are being sent out, the process becomes really slow. Is there a way to optimize this code? I am guessing the cursor is making it slow so I want to explore a different code for this process.

Comment: How do you call that T-SQL? From a trigger? Or from the client app?

Comment: The way your code is written it would appear you have many ItemBalance records for a single ItemId. But how do you know what order they are in? And do you need multiple records (history) or a single record (current state)?

Comment: Previously, it is on a trigger. I am now moving it to a different application wherein that application will do all the backend jobs.

Comment: Same items may have different costs. This loop will update the cost of the record being sent out.

Comment: Have you by chance simplified your SQL? Because the code you have above is choosing all records for the selected ItemId which have a remaining quantity. There no select or update based on cost, and the order the records are processed in the cursor is random which seems odd.

Comment: I think some sample data might be required to illustrate the problem better.

Comment: I modified the query. Actually there is a transaction date on the item balance table and the cursor is ordered by that but I opt not to include it on the code above as my question is whether there is a simpler way to do this without using a cursor.

Comment: Is the comment /* do something with cost */ the one you are asking? What it does is it sums up all the cost fetched from the cursor then update the cost of the item on the sentout table.

Comment: Its difficult to answer when you've removed fundamental aspects of the code because we can't appreciate the full intention of the code in order to advise on the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you just need a simple `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE dbo.itembalance
SET Qty = CASE WHEN Qty >= @qty_to_be_deducted THEN Qty - @qty_to_be_deducted ELSE 0 END
WHERE ItemID = @v_item_to_be_updated
  --What is the difference between Qty and RemainingQty?
  --Why are you checking one and updating the other?
  AND RemainingQty > 0;
```

Comment: If Im going to use a case here, it will update all the records with the same item on the itembalance table.  So if I have Item "A" written multiple times with 100 quantity each and I only want to deduct 20, all of them will be updated which I dont want to happen. I need to deduct only the quantities that are being sent out.

Answer (score 0):

You code is not very clear as to how and why the mechanism is required and works.

However assuming that you must have multiple records with an outstanding balance, and that you must consider multiple records sequentially as part of this mechanism, then you have two options to solve that within SQL (handling in client code is another option):

1) Use a cursor as you have done

2) Use a temp table or table variable and iterate over it - pretty similar to a cursor but might be faster - you'd have to try and see e.g.

```
declare @TableVariable table (Cost money, RemainingQty int, Id int, OrderBy int, Done bit default(0))
declare @Id int, @Cost money, @RemainingQty int

insert into @TableVariable (Cost, RemainingQty, Id, OrderBy)
  SELECT 
    itembalance.Cost 
    , itembalance.RemainingQty
    , itembalance.Id
    , 1 /* Some order by condition */
  FROM dbo.itembalance
  WHERE itembalance.ItemID = @v_item_to_be_updated AND RemainingQty > 0

while exists (select 1 from @TableVariable where Done = 0) begin
  select top 1 @Id = id, @Cost = Cost, @RemainingQty
  from @TableVariable
  where Done = 0
  order by OrderBy

  -- Do stuff here

  update @TableVariable set Done = 1 where id = @Id
end
```

However the code you have shown doesn't appear that it should be slow - so it may be that you are lacking the appropriate indexes, and that a single ItemId update is locking too many rows in the ItemBalance table which is then affecting other ItemId updates.

Comment: will moving the data to a temporary table affect the result say for example multiple users access the same item at once?

Comment: Yes, but the same is true of the cursor... you would need to lock all the rows that might be updated for the duration either way. There is quite likely a better overall design for this issue.